# Worker Type and Driver Type Settings in Databricks with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, cluster-computing, databricks, threadpoolexecutor

I want to run ThreadPoolExecutor() in Databricks for 26 threads. However it times out still after 45min even if I have 26 threads running.

I don't think I have my worker or driver type settings correct in Databricks.

The time to run this code should only take max 20 min if all 26 jobs are working at the same time.

Does anyone know if this is the reason why I cannot run all 26 threads at the same time?

The current cluster settings are:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

def processAnIntegerNumber(START):
  dbutils.notebook.run(path = "/Users/nickknauer1@gmail.com/Ticker_Price_Prediction",
                                        timeout_seconds = 2700, 
                                        arguments = {"START":START})

listOfNumbers = `["1:500","501:1000","1001:1500","1501:2000","2001:2500","2501:3000","3001:3500","3501:4000","4001:4500","4501:5000","5001:5500","5501:6000","5001:5500","5501:6000","6001:6500","6501:7000","7001:7500","7501:8000","8001:8500","8501:9000","9001:9500","9501:10000","10001:10500","10501:11000","11001:11500","11501:12000"]`
with ThreadPoolExecutor(26) as executor:
  results = executor.map(processAnIntegerNumber, listOfNumbers)
```

This produces 26 jobs:

```
Notebook job #854127233194966
Notebook job #598515092856697
Notebook job #698888042699647
Notebook job #521308903687621
Notebook job #833774957866049
Notebook job #967838289186350
Notebook job #1044656684371779
Notebook job #967728381316488
Notebook job #756103818481769
Notebook job #741571723642216
Notebook job #305407888725604
Notebook job #750971338842454
Notebook job #364541218225804
Notebook job #546789683043714
Notebook job #990076496894968
Notebook job #891315472543179
Notebook job #581596503752099
Notebook job #440871497774881
Notebook job #244651017943245
Notebook job #37565644804918
Notebook job #1013093731112037
Notebook job #206008865032730
Notebook job #702612260313649
Notebook job #449829028183619
Notebook job #988510834430189
Notebook job #352412251594948
Notebook job #1009868477781987
Notebook job #253401804409472
Notebook job #725192903682173
Notebook job #247174921415516
Notebook job #468244980716449
Notebook job #619622249572242
Notebook job #623722409320239
Notebook job #1062537954502394
Notebook job #232366090430858
Notebook job #1120897464937076
Notebook job #957077770729470
Notebook job #580409630523552
Notebook job #870069421036075
Notebook job #669465748375934
Notebook job #698596574571091
Notebook job #583143393809739
```

EDIT:
Underlying code within "/Users/nickknauer1@gmail.com/Ticker_Price_Prediction":

For context, I am trying to predict future stock prices for all 12K stocks within NYSE. This list of numbers `1:500`, `501:1000`, etc. represent the ticker number associated with the ticker name. So for example, in each job I am trying to predict the future price for 500 stocks/tickers. The underlying code to do the model can be found below:

All ML work is done in R.

Step 1: Call 500 stocks/tickers with historical stock prices from Snowflake.

Step 2: Predict future values for each stock price (500 filtered)

```
data_new = latest_combined_stock_data %>%  
  group_by(TICKER) %>%
  mutate(weekdays = weekdays(ds)) %>% 
  filter(weekdays != "Saturday" & weekdays != "Sunday") %>%
  do(predict(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), 
             filter(make_future_dataframe(prophet(., daily.seasonality = TRUE, yearly.seasonality = TRUE), periods = 14), weekdays(ds) != "Saturday" & weekdays(ds) != "Sunday"))) %>%
  select(ds, TICKER, yhat)
data_new$ds <- as.Date(data_new$ds)
```

Since there are 12K, I separated it into 26 independent jobs (500 stocks per job) to make it run faster.

Answer (score 1):

You basically starting 26 **independent** Spark jobs that are executed concurrently on the same cluster, fighting for resources like memory and CPU, and not sharing ML model or something like (guessing from the notebook name).  Instead of doing it this way, it's recommended to re-think how the code is executed in the called notebook and try to perform all computations as a single job.  But it's hard to say without knowing the code in the called notebook

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Alex Ott. I added more context in the original question. Technically all 12K predictions will share 1 ML model - `prophet` from FB. I thought this would be the best way to do it However, if you think there is a better method to run this code, I would definitely be interested to hear alternatives. https://facebook.github.io/prophet/

Comment: On top of this, the underlying R code already runs 500 regression models using the `do` function with `group_by` from `dplyr` package. I thought this would be most efficient. However, I am just learning about utilizing worker types in databricks and it's capability with regression at scale. Would love any advice if you have worked on something like this in the past. Thanks!

Comment: You can't speedup it by using the same cluster. It's better to try to parallelize it using Spark, because I think that your model doesn't utilize workers at all. You can look into this blog posts for examples: https://databricks.com/blog/2021/04/06/fine-grained-time-series-forecasting-at-scale-with-facebook-prophet-and-apache-spark-updated-for-spark-3.html, https://databricks.com/blog/2020/01/27/time-series-forecasting-prophet-spark.html, especially first one (although it's in Python)

Comment: Very helpful, will read up more on this. Thanks!

Comment: My last comment regarding this is that I do see improvement when using threadpoolexecutor() on this. The only difference is that it doesn't improve if I switch from 8 to 26 jobs. So I think it's doing something for sure but when increasing it, no difference is made on job execution speed. I'll read more on the links you sent though, they seem right in line with what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks @alex ott